# Mapping input responses into an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in jQuery that returns an array called responses. The array returned is based on the
position of the input elements.

```
var resp = $("input[id^= 'Answer_Response']");
responses: jQuery.map(resp, function (a) { return a.checked; })

<input id="Answer_Response[2]" name="Answer.Response[2]" type="checkbox" /> 
<input id="Answer_Response[0]" name="Answer.Response[0]" type="checkbox" />
<input id="Answer_Response[1]" name="Answer.Response[1]" type="checkbox" />
<input id="Answer_Response[4]" name="Answer.Response[4]" type="checkbox" />
<input id="Answer_Response[3]" name="Answer.Response[3]" type="checkbox" />
```

so When the inputs are:

```
 false    // for Answer.Response[2]
 true     // for Answer.Response[0]
 true     // for Answer.Response[1]
 false    // for Answer.Response[4]
 true     // for Answer.Response[3]
```

the responses array looks like false, true, true, false, true

what I need is for the array returned to be based on the id number for the elements. So for example I need an
array returned that looks like this: true, true, false, true, false

```
  true    // for Answer.Response[0]
  true    // for Answer.Response[1]
  false   // for Answer.Response[2]
  true    // for Answer.Response[3]
  false   // for Answer.Response[4]
```

Is there some way that I can do this in jQuery? please note that I can't change the way that the responses are displayed. I've been asked to do this all in jQuery.

I hope someone can give some advice. I guess I just need some different way to do the mapping of resp but I'm not sure how I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```
var resp = [ ];
$("input[id^= 'Answer_Response']").each(function() {
    // Pull the number out of things like "Answer.Response[2]"
    var i   = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
    resp[i] = this.checked;
});
```

That should get the job done as long as the `id` attributes have exactly one substring that looks like a number (or at least the first match is the one you want) and there aren't any gaps in your `id` attributes (or you'll get some undefined entries in your `resp` array).

And a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hHS2K/